# Selenium - output system logs to text file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to get the network logs output to a text file, I have network log starting but i cant figure out how to output it to a text file

I have the below code but im not sure how to export it to a text file

```
            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
            logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
            caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Logs logs = driver.manage().logs();
LogEntries logEntries = logs.get(LogType.DRIVER); // or other logType

List<String> lines = logEntries.getAll().stream().map(LogEntry::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

//Write data to some file.
Files.write(Paths.get("someFile"), lines);
```